# Filling JSON content from database

Tags: javascript, html

I tried for hours before asking you for help. I'm so sorry for wasting your time. But please help me, I'm really hungry to learn. I'm sorry for my bad english.
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-chart-images-top/

I am working on a project with MVC entities(Mysql). I want to fill the contents of this chart with A1(string) and A2(int) fields of table A.
Thank You.

```js
am5.ready(function () {

    // Create root element
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
    var root = am5.Root.new("Personel_Grafik");

    // Set themes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
    root.setThemes([
        am5themes_Animated.new(root)
    ]);

    // Create chart
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
    var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
        panX: false,
        panY: false,
        wheelX: "none",
        wheelY: "none"
    }));

    // Add cursor
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/cursor/
    var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {}));
    cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);

    // Create axes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
    var xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, { minGridDistance: 30 });

    var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
        maxDeviation: 0,
        categoryField: "name",
        renderer: xRenderer,
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
    }));

    xRenderer.grid.template.set("visible", false);

    var yRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {});
    var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
        maxDeviation: 0,
        min: 0,
        extraMax: 0.1,
        renderer: yRenderer
    }));

    yRenderer.grid.template.setAll({
        strokeDasharray: [2, 2]
    });

    // Create series
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
    var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
        name: "Series 1",
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        valueYField: "value",
        sequencedInterpolation: true,
        categoryXField: "name",
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, { dy: -25, labelText: "{valueY}" })
    }));


    series.columns.template.setAll({
        cornerRadiusTL: 5,
        cornerRadiusTR: 5
    });

    series.columns.template.adapters.add("fill", (fill, target) => {
        return chart.get("colors").getIndex(series.columns.indexOf(target));
    });

    series.columns.template.adapters.add("stroke", (stroke, target) => {
        return chart.get("colors").getIndex(series.columns.indexOf(target));
    });

    // Set data
    var data = [
        {
            name: "John",
            value: 35654,
            bulletSettings: { src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/faces/A04.png" }
        },
        {
            name: "Damon",
            value: 65456,
            bulletSettings: { src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/faces/C02.png" }
        },
        {
            name: "Patrick",
            value: 45724,
            bulletSettings: { src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/faces/D02.png" }
        },
        {
            name: "Mark",
            value: 13654,
            bulletSettings: { src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/faces/E01.png" }
        }
    ];

    series.bullets.push(function () {
        return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
            locationY: 1,
            sprite: am5.Picture.new(root, {
                templateField: "bulletSettings",
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                centerX: am5.p50,
                centerY: am5.p50,
                shadowColor: am5.color(0x000000),
                shadowBlur: 4,
                shadowOffsetX: 4,
                shadowOffsetY: 4,
                shadowOpacity: 0.6
            })
        });
    });

    xAxis.data.setAll(data);
    series.data.setAll(data);

    // Make stuff animate on load
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
    series.appear(1000);
    chart.appear(1000, 100);

}); // end am5.ready()
```

```css
#Personel_Grafik {
    width: 100%;
    height: 265px;

}
```

```html
<div id="Personel_Grafik2"></div>
```

Comment: It looks like your data is already in `var data`. What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: I want to get data from already var data in database. I want to transfer data from database to Var Data

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about what kind of database you're using and how you can connect to it to retrieve the data.

Comment: TestEntities _db = new TestEntities(); //Model
I provide a link. I am using mysql. I don't know exactly how to provide this information.

Comment: What language is that? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71357853/edit) to include *all* the code relevant to this issue. If you are using MySQL, you will also have to tag your question with the server-side language you are using to connect to the MySQL DB (e.g. Python, PHP, etc.).

Comment: MVC asp.net and c# use

Comment: Are you going to help?

Comment: Not until you edit your question to include the details I requested.